# doubt -mysqli+php function

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, mysqli

i have this `function insert ()`

the function insert data in the table `users` and sent an email.

I need to terminate a previous state before create another one, correct?
so, i need to store the activation link in another table, the `activationLinks` table.

i can make something like this? i think the code below doesn't work.

```
($sql = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO users, activationLinks (username, email, password) (link) VALUES (?, ?, ?) (?)"));
```

basically the question, is that i need  store data in two different tables, but in the same function.
thanks

Comment: Why you don't just send two queries?

Comment: `INSERT INTO users ...` and then `INSERT INTO activationLinks ...` (or vice versa)

Comment: if you post your answer i will accept, works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments: Just send two separate `INSERT`-queries

```
INSERT INTO users ...
INSERT INTO activationLinks ...
```

You may also wrap them into a transaction

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO users ...
INSERT INTO activationLinks ...
COMMIT;
```